# How to iterate through a collection on my view going down and then across columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails

To preface, I'm not terribly familiar with CSS and I suspect I may have to utilize that as well so any help would be appreciated on that front.

I am trying to iterate through a collection which will always have at least 15 members but never more than 30.  On my view, the first 15 should be displayed in the first/left column, and any remaining members on the next/right column.

I am populating a template and thus the need for the somewhat rigid requirements.

Is there any way to generate this dynamically?  As in, just write one (or two) html tr tags in my view?

Ideal output would be like this:

```
[1...20]

1  16
2  17
3  18
4  19
5  20
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `each_slice(15)` which will split your collection into 2 chunks of 15 elements then you can map each element of the second chunk to the first chunk by using a `map.with_index` and using the index to determine which element to map it too

like so:

```
irb(main):012:0> slice_1, slice_2 = array.each_slice(15).to_a 
=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]
irb(main):013:0> result = slice_1.map.with_index { |element, index| [element, slice_2.to_a[index]] } #
=> [[1, 16], [2, 17], [3, 18], [4, 19], [5, 20], [6, 21], [7, 22], [8, 23], [9, 24], [10, 25], [11, nil], [12, nil], [13, nil], [14, nil], [15, nil]]
```

and then do a nested iteration first iteration determine the column and the second the rows or vis-versa depending on what you need

```
<% array = (1..9) %>
<% slice_1, slice_2 = array.each_slice(15).to_a %>
<% result = slice_1.map.with_index { |element, index| [element, slice_2.to_a[index]] } %> # to_a on second slice in case array has < 15 element

<% result.each do |row| %>
  <tr>
  <% row.each do |e| %>
    <td><%= e %> </td>
  <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried that but it made one row of 1-15, and then the next row was 16-20.  Not in columns though.

Comment: @JeffO I updated the answer to show in columns of 2 only